Problem with a proof in Friedman's Foundations of Modern Analysis
I'm having trouble with a particular step in a proof in Friedman's Foundations of Modern Analysis. At this point in the book, integrals of simple functions have been dealt with, and in the current section we are defining the integral of a general integrable function. This is the lemma I am having trouble with:

Lemma 2.6.3 Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of integrable simple functions satisfying (a), (b), and let
$$\lambda(E) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_E f_n d \mu$$
for any measurable set $E$. Then $\lambda(E)$ is a completely additive set function.

The referenced properties (a), (b) are

(a) $\{f_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in the mean.
(b) $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = f(x)$ a.e.

Now, in the proof we suppose that $E$ is a disjoint union $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty E_i$ of measurable sets $E_i$. In a particular step the author claims that, for any $\epsilon > 0$,
$$\left| \int_{\bigcup_{i=1}^m E_i} f_n d \mu - \lambda \left( \bigcup_{i=1}^m E_i \right) \right| < \frac{\epsilon}{2} \tag{1}$$
for all $n \ge n_0$, where $n_0$ is sufficiently large, depending on $\epsilon$, but not on $m$.
How can we conclude that $n_0$ does not depend on $m$?

(1) is quite non-trivial. I am sure the previous steps in the proof are relevant for this.

@geetha290krm Thanks. I think I see it now. The author shows right at the beginning of the proof that the limit defining $\lambda(E)$ exists uniformly with respect to $E$. I didn't quite realize the implications of the qualifier "uniformly", but of course that means that we can choose $n_0$ such that (1) holds for all $m$ when $n > n_0$.

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Using property (a), choose $n_{0}\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $k,n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $k\geq n_{0}$ and $n\geq n_{0}$ one has
\begin{equation}
\int |f_{n} - f_{k}| \, d\mu \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{4}.
\end{equation}
Fix $n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $n\geq n_{0}$. Let $E$ be a measurable set. Then
\begin{align*}
\Big| \int_{E} f_{n} \, d\mu - \lambda (E) \Big| &= \lim_{k\to\infty} \Big| \int_{E} f_{n} \, d\mu - \int_{E} f_{k} \, d\mu \Big| \\
&\leq \limsup_{k\to\infty} \int_{E} |f_{n} - f_{k}| \, d\mu \\
&\leq \limsup_{k\to\infty} \int |f_{n} - f_{k}| \, d\mu \\
&\leq \tfrac{\varepsilon}{4} < \tfrac{\varepsilon}{2} .
\end{align*}
Hence there exists $n_{0}\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $n\geq n_{0}$ and all measurable sets $E$ one has
\begin{equation}
\Big| \int_{E} f_{n} \, d\mu - \lambda (E) \Big| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}. \tag{$\ast$}
\end{equation}
In particular, ($\ast$) holds with $E = \bigcup_{i=1}^{m}E_{i}$ for every $m\in\mathbb{N}$.

Thank you. I see now that the important thing is that the limit defining $\lambda(E)$ exists uniformly with respect to $E$, which you have proven here. This is actually shown in Friedman's proof as well (though with less detail) right at the beginning, but I didn't quite realize the implications of the uniformity.
